# Working with recursive functions

Tags: c++, recursion

I am writing a program that will help us understand how recursive functions work by creating a simple dice game. But for some reason the output is wrong and I don't know why. I am getting this:

[image]

When I should be getting something like this:

[image]

Here is the code I have:

```
    #include <iostream>
//function prototype:
int payoff(int x, int y, int z);

void loopR1(int R1, int upto);
void loopR2(int R2, int upto);
void loopR3(int R3, int upto);

//global variables:
int total;

using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    cout << "R1\t R2\t R3\t\n" << endl;

    ////////////////////
    //first loop
    ////////////////////
    loopR1(1, 4);
    printf("\n");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void loopR1(int R1, int upto)
{
    while (R1 < upto){
        loopR2(R1, upto);
        R1++;
    }
}
void loopR2(int R2, int upto)
{
    while (R2 < upto){
        loopR3(R2, upto);
        R2++;
    }
}
void loopR3(int R3, int upto)
{
    int R1 = 1;
    int R2 = 1;
    while (R3 < upto){
        printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t payoff is %d\n", R1, R2, R3, payoff(R1, R2, R3));
        R3++;
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//FUNCTIONS:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int payoff(int R1, int R2, int R3) {
    if (R2 < R1) {
        total = total + R2;
    } //end if
    else {
        if (R3 < R1) {
            total = total + R3;
        } //end if
        else {
            total = R1;
        } // end else
    } //end else


    if (R3 < R2) {
        total = total + (2 * R3);
    } //end if
    else {
        if (R3 < R1) {
            total = total + R3;
        } //end if
        else {
            total = R1;
        } //end else
    } //end else

    return total;
} //end function payoff
```

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong and how to make it loop correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: I am so sorty, I forgot to add it. Many apologies. Could I please get my points back? It was a mistake.

Comment: Good, the code is now included. But what are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: The problem may be that you're using `if` instead of `while` in each of your loopR# functions.

Comment: basically is to get loopR3 method to loop correctly and display the results as it shows in the second picture. I want to loop R1-R2 values from 1 to 3 and display the correct output

Comment: @mah I tried that but it gives me an infinite loop

Comment: @ManuelMangual taking a step that doesn't solve the problem but instead leads to a new one does not mean you're taking a backwards step... it can also mean you have more than one problem. For example, I suspect in loopR3 you also mean to increment R3 (which is consistent with your other loopR functions). That will make your code terminate reasonable, though there's still something wrong with the output I think.

Comment: I updated my code and output to let you guys know what I changed. But the output is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your code includes the following function:

```
void loopR3(int R3, int upto)
{
    int R1 = 1;
    int R2 = 1;
    while (R3 < upto){
        printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t payoff is %d\n", R1, R2, R3, payoff(R1, R2, R3));
        R3++;
    }
}
```

Based on the context, what you probably wanted to do was to pass in the values of R1 and R2 rather than declare local versions and initialize them each to the value 1.

Alternatively, since you're using C++, you might consider creating an object to hold all three values and the value of `total` (the function of which is unclear from your code).  If you do that, you could also create a function to print out the values (and perhaps use `iostream` instead of `printf`).

Comment: I tried that but it is still wrong. Though the value in R2 actually changed, but it should have updated that change some rows ago and it only does it towards the end. But thank you though.